# Show Different Header on a Specific Post ID

Tags: custom-post-types, php, custom-header

I am needing to show a different header for a specific page.

I created a custom page template that calls/shows the normal header that the entire website uses.
I am using this page template for about 50 pages.

Now, I need only one of those pages to show a different header.
This header will be very similar to the normal one, but I will use a different contact number (using this specific page for online ads).

**To Create the New Header**
I am thinking I could duplicate the code on the original header, change the mentioned contact number, name the header something like header-second.php.

Here is the only bit of code that will be changing for the new/second header. Only the phone number will change...

```
<div class="row-two">
<div style ="float: right; margin-right: 16px; margin-top: 10px;"><p 
class="headersample1"><a href="/request-a-quote/">REQUEST QUOTE</a></p></div>
<div style ="float: right; margin-top: 10px;"><p class="headersample2">OR 
</p></div>
<div style ="float: right; margin-top: 10px;"><p class="headersample3"><a 
href="tel:555-555-5555">555-555-5555</a></p></div>
</div>
```

**Assign New Header to Specific Page**
Any ideas how I can assign a different header to show on a specific post ID? This page uses the same custom page template that about 50 other pages use, so I can't call this new header in the custom page template...I don't think.

Comment: How much of your header changes?  If it is only the phone number, a very easy solution is a condition in the header.php file.

Comment: Edited original question with the code used in the header.php file.

Comment: If only the phone number changes, I would definitely recommend the first example.  I will edit to be more explicit to your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your header.php file, you can test which page is loading and modify the markup based on this condition.  For your example, the `is_page()` function seems ideal.

```
<div style ="float: right; margin-top: 10px;">
    <p class="headersample3">
    <?php if ( is_page( '###' ) ) { ?>
        <a href="tel:555-555-5555">555-555-5555</a>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <a href="tel:888-888-8888">888-888-8888</a>
    <?php } ?>
    </p>
</div>
```

Replacing the ### with your actual page ID.

If you truly need to load an entirely different header file for this one page, then you would test `is_page()` in the page template and then conditionally load the header file you want.

```
if ( is_page( '543' ) {
    get_header( '543' );  // file name is actually header-543.php
} else {
    get_header();
}
```

Note: The parameter passed to `get_header()` is not the full file name.  See the Codex for more detail https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_header/

Also, a good naming practice is to follow the WP core standards. A header for a specific page ID should be named header-pageid.php

EDIT: updated to reflect code added to question.

Comment: This updated code is working exactly as I needed!
    <div style ="float: right; margin-top: 10px;">
    <p class="headersample3">
    <?php if ( is_page( '###' ) ) { ?>
    <a href="tel:555-555-5555">555-555-5555</a>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <a href="tel:888-888-8888">888-888-8888</a>
    <?php } ?>
    </p>
    </div>

Comment: This is great to target one specific page. Is it possible to target more than one page?

I tried these examples, but nothing worked:
<?php if ( is_page( '123456,123457' ) ) { ?>

<?php if ( is_page( 123456,123457 ) ) { ?>

Comment: `is_page()` accepts an array.  Your examples are not valid PHP arrays.  Try `is_page( array( '123', '456', '789' ) )`.   You might also create the array separately and then use that variable as the argument e.g. `is_page( $page_ids )`

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Glad it worked for you.  Happy to help.